# Outlook VBA works in editor but not under rule

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Have cobbled some code together to extract the body of a specific email I receive daily and copy it to an excel workbook.

It will run in editor manually, but when applying it to a rule in outlook based on the words in the subject body, it will only open a new excel workbook.

Will not give an error as well.

I have read and research through the forums to get it to this level to work ” thanks to the CODE GOD’S”.

Any direction or advise on getting this to work under a rule(run a script) would be much appreciated.

Code below:

```
Public Sub SaveEmailBody(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

    Dim outlookApp As New Outlook.Application
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Fldr As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim olMail As Variant
    Dim myTasks
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim myXLApp As Excel.Application
    Dim myXLWB As Excel.Workbook
    Dim aFile As String
    Dim TotalRows As Long, i As Long

    'Delete yesterday's file
    aFile = "C:\Reporting\Input_files\Volume.xls"
    If Len(Dir$(aFile)) > 0 Then
    Kill aFile
    End If

    Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNs = outlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set myTasks = Fldr.Items
    Set myXLApp = New Excel.Application
    myXLApp.Visible = True
    Set myXLWB = myXLApp.Workbooks.Add

    'Find today's volume email
    For Each olMail In myTasks
    If (InStr(1, olMail.Body, "ListVolume", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        TotalRows = Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
        i = TotalRows + 1 - 1

            With myXLWB.Worksheets(1)
            '.Cells(i, 1) = Format(myItem.SentOn, "mm/dd/yyyy")
            '.Cells(i, 2) = myItem.SenderName
            '.Cells(i, 3) = myItem.To
            .Cells(i, 1) = olMail.Body

            'Save today's volume email
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:="C:\Reporting\Input_files\Volume.xls", FileFormat:= _
            xlNormal, Password:="", WriteResPassword:="", ReadOnlyRecommended:=False _
            , CreateBackup:=False

            Set outlookApp = Nothing
            myXLApp.Quit
            Set myXLApp = Nothing
            End With
        Exit For
    End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28934579/how-i-can-run-macro-automatically-with-new-email-arrives-in-outlook

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to create a new Outlook Application instance in the VBA macro:

```
Set outlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
```

Instead, you need to use the Application property available in the VBA module:

Set outlookApp = Application

Also I see that you iterate over all tasks:

```
'Find today's volume email
For Each olMail In myTasks
```

I suppose you want to get some information from the incoming email message instead. If so, you need to use the argument passed to the sub instead:

```
Public Sub SaveEmailBody(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
```

The **itm** object represents the incoming email message. Use it in the code instead.